# Многопоточность в боте ВК Python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

пишу бота для ВК, с использованием vk_api .
Столкнулся с проблемой, что когда боту пишет много человек, то всех их он обрабатывает поочередно и последний может очень долго ждать ответа, так как есть сложные задачи.

ПОдскажите, как решить сию проблему

Comment: Вынести сложные задачи в отдельные потоки. Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос заголовком, больше ответить тут нечего

Answer (score 1):

думаю, самое простое - это использовать [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), вынести туда тяжёлые задачи

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите в сторону асинхронности. В питоне это `asyncio`. Также — да. Можно вынести в отдельные потоки. Это уже `threading`. Сам не разобрался с асинхронностью еще до конца, поэтому пишу на многопоточной модели. Если интересно: https://github.com/icYFTL/ZalgoBot